# Out Of Memory Exception while running a loop

Tags: c#, .net

I am confused at this point I have the following code:

```
            while (dal.Read())
            {

                if (FiltersAppliedForThisJob(dal.GetInt(0)))
                   continue;
                var j = 0;
                if (SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.JobViewServiceList.IsNotNull() &&
                    SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.JobViewServiceList.Count > 0)
                    if (!ThisJobHasASupportedService(dal.GetInt(0)))
                        continue;

                var newJobGridRow = AddRowToJobGridWithJobID(dal.GetInt(0),
                                                             ref j);
                BoldThisJobGridRowIfItIsUpdated(newJobGridRow, dal);
                var jobno = dal2.GetJobNo(dal.GetInt(0).ToString());
                if (locns2view.Length > 0)
                    _jobgrid.Rows[newJobGridRow].Visible = locns2view.Contains(jobno.Substring(0, 2));

                var col = 2;
                if (j < _jobgrid.ColumnCount)
                    for (i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (str1[i].Length <= 0)
                            continue;

                        if (!dal.IsFieldNull(col))
                            PlaceValuesInJobGridCells(dtype, i, dal2, str1, jobno, newJobGridRow, j, dal, col);
                        j++;
                        col++;
                    }
                if (_jobgrid[0, newJobGridRow].Value.ToString() == prevjobid)
                    _jobgrid.Rows[newJobGridRow].Selected = true;
            }

            SortJobGridColumns();
        }
```

It seems that the out of memory error is coming from the code above.  However, if I put a MessageBox before I call `FiltersAppliedForThisJob(dal.GetInt(0)`, I get no error.  For example the code below:

```
            while (dal.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Done"); // for debugging purposes

                if (FiltersAppliedForThisJob(dal.GetInt(0)))
                   continue;
                var j = 0;
                if (SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.JobViewServiceList.IsNotNull() &&
                    SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.JobViewServiceList.Count > 0)
                    if (!ThisJobHasASupportedService(dal.GetInt(0)))
                        continue;

                var newJobGridRow = AddRowToJobGridWithJobID(dal.GetInt(0),
                                                             ref j);
                BoldThisJobGridRowIfItIsUpdated(newJobGridRow, dal);
                var jobno = dal2.GetJobNo(dal.GetInt(0).ToString());
                if (locns2view.Length > 0)
                    _jobgrid.Rows[newJobGridRow].Visible = locns2view.Contains(jobno.Substring(0, 2));

                var col = 2;
                if (j < _jobgrid.ColumnCount)
                    for (i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (str1[i].Length <= 0)
                            continue;

                        if (!dal.IsFieldNull(col))
                            PlaceValuesInJobGridCells(dtype, i, dal2, str1, jobno, newJobGridRow, j, dal, col);
                        j++;
                        col++;
                    }
                if (_jobgrid[0, newJobGridRow].Value.ToString() == prevjobid)
                    _jobgrid.Rows[newJobGridRow].Selected = true;
            }

            SortJobGridColumns();
        }
```

Also, if I remove the function call `FiltersAppliedForThisJob(dal.GetInt(0)`, I don't get an the error.

Here is the function code:

```
  private bool FiltersAppliedForThisJob(int p)
    {
        var filter_datefrom = SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.MainView_DateFrom;
        var filter_dateto = SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.MainView_DateTo;
        var filter_status = SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.MainView_JobStatus;
        var jobNumTbl = dal.Get_JobNumber(p);
        var jobStatus = GetJobStatus(p);
        var jobdate = jobNumTbl.Date;
        var jobdate_res = false;
        var jobstat_res = false;
        var isFiltered = false;

        if (jobdate.HasValue)
        {
            //both have values
            if (filter_datefrom.HasValue && filter_dateto.HasValue)
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(jobdate.Value.Date, filter_datefrom.Value.Date) < 0 ||
                    DateTime.Compare(jobdate.Value.Date, filter_dateto.Value.Date) > 0)
                    jobdate_res = true;
            }
            //only datefrom has value
            else if (filter_datefrom.HasValue)
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(jobdate.Value.Date, filter_datefrom.Value.Date) < 0)
                    jobdate_res = true;
            }
            //only datato has value
            else if (filter_dateto.HasValue)
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(jobdate.Value.Date, filter_dateto.Value.Date) > 0)
                    jobdate_res = true;
            }
        }

        if (jobStatus.HasValue)
        {
            if (!filter_status.Equals(2))
                if (!filter_status.Equals(jobStatus))
                    jobstat_res = true;
        }

        if (jobdate_res || jobstat_res)
            isFiltered = true;


        return isFiltered;
    }
```

Not sure if this is enough information.  If you need more from me, let me know.

Comment: Did you debug it and see how many times it is called, also check task manager to see the memory used each loop

Comment: that's alot of code, could you narrow down the search ?

Comment: Yeah, task manager jumps really high unless I throw that MessageBox in there or remove the `FiltersAppliedForThisJob` function call

Comment: I dont see what you do before the dal.read() but if you do a .open(), do you close it after? or .Dispose()?

Comment: Put a break point on the method that contains your `while` loop. When it hits it, then hit F5. If it hits it again, check your Call Stack to see where it's coming from. If that's not the culprit, then try it with the other methods you're calling in there. You might have a recursive call without knowing it.

Comment: What is the stack trace from when the OutOfMemoryException occurs?

Comment: Can you count how many time 'FiltersAppliedForThisJob(dal.GetInt(0))' is TRUE? you could try putting a delay instead of the message box (like wait for a second). By the way what is 'dal'?

Comment: I tried putting a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in place of the MessageBox but that didn't work

Comment: If setting do not change between calls I would move 4 SettingsManager. out of that routine.  Read them once and store them in a private variable.  Might fix the OOM.  But only a comment.

Comment: What's really bad is, I can't duplicate the problem on my development machine.  Only certain users have the issue.  so I found one of the users and tried debugging it from his machine. Still trying to figure this thing out.

Comment: I managed to get a copy of the user's database on his machine.  So I should be able to debug to see exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Well, looks like the `FiltersAppliedForThisJob(dal.GetInt(0))` is never `False`.  Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  The application was pulling all of the information from the database before filtering, which is a lot of data.  I added extra filtering to the query before loading the data. Everything is fine now.  Thanks everyone